# How to toggle minicart in Bigcommerce cornerstone theme?

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce

I believe cornerstone already have a mini cart, I just can't find where to toggle it.
So I need to toggle a mini-cart like this:

[image: example mini-cart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cornerstone does not have a side mini-cart like your example. There is a dropdown mini-cart by default, but it is not too detailed. You can see the default Cornerstone mini-cart by adding an item to your cart and then clicking "Cart" in the header. https://cornerstone-light-demo.mybigcommerce.com/

[image: Cornerstone Mini Cart]

You may want to look through the theme store for a theme that has a mini-cart like the one you desire. https://www.bigcommerce.com/theme-store/

Comment: but where is the code that toggles the mini-cart to appear? also what file is the mini-cart, I'm going to update the code instead of changing theme. Do you need to change theme to implement a different style of mini-cart?

Comment: I suppose you could edit this one to look as you desire. You will want to look at templates/components/common/cart-preview.html and assets/js/theme/global/cart-preview.js